# Request.args as filters from several path levels

Tags: python, rest, flask

I would know if it's possible to get request.args from different path levels.

Currently i can use request.args for only one level :

```
my_ip:my_port/modules/?name=git
```

or

```
my_ip:my_port/modules/?id=0
```

```
@module_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_modules():

    if len(request.args) == 0:
        modules = Module.query.all()
        return jsonify(modules=list_to_json(modules))

    try:
        module = Module.query.filter_by(**request.args.to_dict()).first()
    except InvalidRequestError as i:
        return json_response(400, "InvalidRequestError : {}".format(i.args))

    if module is None:
        return json_response(204, "")

    return jsonify(module=module.serialize)
```

But in my Module model I have actions and I would like to get actions in the same way :

```
my_ip:my_port/modules/?name=git/actions/?id=0
```

But I don't know how to do this.

If I try with

```
@module_blueprint.route('/actions', methods=['GET'])
```

request.args just keep args after the action path

```
my_ip:my_port/modules/?name=git/actions
```

request.args is empty for this path

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Request params are always appended at the end of the request url. Everything after a **?** is considered URI Params. Thus, a url like

> my_ip:my_port/modules/?name=git/actions/?id=0

is not possible since it violates the above mentioned guideline.

### Solution if there is going to be only 1 param per level:

In this case, passing the info as params does not provide any advantage. Thus, the following would be a better way of doing things:

For fetching module by name:

```
@module_blueprint.route('/<module_name>', methods=['GET'])
```

For fetching actions for that module:

```
@module_blueprint.route('/<module_name>/action/<int:action_id>', methods=['GET'])
```

### Solution if there are going to be more than 1 filter param per level:

In this case, it makes more sense to use request params.

For fetching module by name:

```
@module_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
```

For fetching actions for that module:

```
@module_blueprint.route('/actions', methods=['GET'])
```